# How do I enter path variable as UUID in postman request?

Tags: spring, api, postman

I have path variable parameter as a UUID, with path as id.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/{id}", produces = "application/json")
public  ResponseEntity<T> getId(@PathVariable("id") final UUID id) {

}
```

when I add this as a String`4df34f48-33ce-4da2-8eba-a682e2d1e698` or as String in brackets`{4df34f48-33ce-4da2-8eba-a682e2d1e698}` in my postman url, I get a 400 Bad Request error.

What can I do to add it here?

Thanks.

Comment: remove final key word and request as /{4df34f48-33ce-4da2-8eba-a682e2d1e698}

Comment: I was passing in an empty request body while running the GET request, that was giving the error @Geeth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `@PathVariable` as part of the function itself:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/{id}", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<UUID> getUID(@PathVariable("id") final UUID id) {
     log.info("id is {}", id);
     return new ResponseEntity<>(id, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

That should then allow you to query it through Postman:

`http://localhost:8080/4df34f48-33ce-4da2-8eba-a682e2d1e698`

Comment: It is a part of a function, I didn't write that explicitly earlier, now I've updated it in the question. And the path variable is a UUID, not a String. @John Chan

Comment: Having it as any other class type do not matter. I tried on both UUID and String and it works.

    `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/{id}", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<UUID> getUID(@PathVariable("id") final UUID id) {
        log.info("id is {}", id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(id, HttpStatus.OK);
    }`

Are you able to share your entire Controller class?

Comment: I think I got my error, I was passing in an empty request body while running the GET request, that was giving the error. thanks!